# ProductDetailComponent.html:451 ERROR TypeError: _co.updateUrl is not a function at Object.eval [as handleEvent]

Tags: angular5

This is my directive class- I am getting below error. please help out
ProductDetailComponent.html:451 ERROR TypeError: _co.updateUrl is not a function     at Object.eval [as handleEvent]

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
selector:"[fallback]",
host: {
'(error)':'updateUrl()',
'[src]':'src'
} 
})

export class FallBackDirective { 
@Input() src:string;
@Input() default:string="assets/images/no-product.jpg";

updateUrl() {
  this.src = this.default;
}
}

 <img src="{{item.ThumbPic | noImage}}" fallback="assets/images/no-product.jpg" (error)="updateUrl($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply don't call custom directive method from image, because once you mention error method in custom directive, it automatically call method on error. just like you mentioned here:

```
'(error)':'updateUrl()'
```

i resolved this issue like this

```
<img fallback src="{{item.ThumbPic | noImage}}">
```